# Download checkpoint from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

How can I download the checkpoints and logged statistics after I run my deep learning algorithm on AWS using SageMaker?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the training job (notebook or GUI it doesn't matter) you have defined an output directory, that usually is a S3 bucket. At the end of the training job, sagemaker automatically upload everything (with everything I mean everything that is [contained](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-output.html) in /opt/ml/model, if you use a predefined container this is automatic, otherwise it's up to you to write you artifact there) in a compressed archive to that output directory. So simply download the archive from S3.